# Redis GET vs. SQL SELECT

Tags: nosql, redis

I am pretty new to NoSQL, but I always liked the idea of it. I took a look at [Redis](http://www.redis.io), and got a few questions about the best ways of storing and recieving multiple `hashes`.

Assuming the following scenario:

```
Store a list of objects (redis 'Hashes') and select them by their timestamp.
```

To archive this in `SQL`, it would require one table and two simple queries (INSERT & SELECT).

Trying to do this in `Redis`, I ended up creating the following structure:

1. Key `object:$id` [(hash)](http://redis.io/topics/data-types#hashes) *containing the `object`*
2. Key `index:timestamp:$id` [(sorted set)](http://redis.io/topics/data-types#sorted-sets)
   *`score` equals `timestamp` and `value` includes `id`*

While I can live with the additional maintenance work of two keys instead of one table  (*SQL*), I am curious about the process of **selecting multiple objects**:

```
ZRANGEBYSCORE index:timestamp:$id timestampStart timestampEnd
```

This returns an `array` of all IDs which got created between `timestampStart` and `timestampEnd`. To get the object itself I am requesting every single one by:

```
GET object:$id
```

- Is this the right way of doing it?
- In comparison with an SQL Database: Is it still appreciably faster or might it even become slower caused by the high number of `GET`s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `ZRANGEBYSCORE` costs `O(log(N) + M)` where `N=|items in your set|` and `M=|items you're selecting|`. So, doing the `ZRANGEBYSCORE` and then M `GET` operations is just `O(long(N)+M+M)` = `O(log(N)+M)` and would at most be twice as slow. The network back and forth could have been a major slow down, but since each of your gets is an independent operation, you can just pipeline them. You can also put the whole thing in a Lua script and just have one back and forth, which would be the most optimal. I'd say with 99% certainty this would be faster than doing the same thing in SQL.

Also, if this is a very frequent operation for you, you can get even more speed up by just storing the entire object in your sorted set instead of just the id. You'd have `key = object encoded as json`, `score = timestamp`. This would save you `O(M)` on your operation in terms of not needing to do any `GET`s.

Whether or not this is a good way of doing things really depends on your use case. How much speed do you really need, and how important are other features of a traditional database to you? Remember, Redis is much more just datastructures accessible by clients than a traditional database, and it must store everything in RAM. To know whether it's the right thing for you, we'd need more information.

Comment: thanks a lot for the work you put into this answer! You just introduced me to Lua script, so I'll read into that. I also thoght about storing the whole `object` inside of the `sorted set`, but then again: what if I have to use more than one index? As far as I know, Redis would use twice as much space because every index would include the whole object and Redis it isn't able to link between them!?

Comment: I thought you were just indexing by one timestamp. Yes, if there are many indexes, it would use more space. Whether the extra space is worth the speed trade-off really depends on your use case.